# How can I keep KeePassX *always* on the current workspace?

Tags: linux, window-manager, workspace

I use KeePassX as my password manager. I am running GNU/Linux Mint with Xfce. I like to keep KeePass always on the visible workspace (which I can do by selecting that option after right-clicking the taskbar icon) so that I can access it from any workspace. The problem is, after using Auto-type, it resets to only being visible on the current workspace. How do I fix this?

I am not sure whether or not this is an Xfce-specific problem; I have not tried to duplicate the problem on any other window managers. Searches online have led nowhere.

Note: I was just reminded that you can set KeePass to minimize to the tray, which is not dependent on the workspace, and is not affected by Auto-type. I will be doing that instead to save space, so I have worked around the problem. I would still like to know the answer though: I am curious why this happens and if there is a way to fix it.